# Cloud Dataflow SQL: Merge Statement not allowed

Tags: python, google-bigquery, airflow, etl, google-cloud-composer

I have two tables, both on Bigquery:

1. Employee(id, name, age) with all the employees (ID is PK).
2. Online(id, name, age) where new employees are added (let's say daily) and/or old ones are modified (ID is PK).

[image: Example tables]

Every day, I want to run a job (with Cloud Composer) that read *ONLINE* table and insert new employees or/and update old ones. This `upsert`  operation is called `MERGE` on Bigquery. I noticed that the Dataflow SQL doesn't allow to run job on Bigquery with the MERGE statement.

[image: Dataflow SQL MERGE statement]

Is there an Airflow Operator (about Bigquery) that I can use instead of  `DataflowStartSqlJobOperator` ?
If yes: is it right to i) delete rows from EMPLOYEE if ID is in ONLINE; ii) add ONLINE rows into EPLOYEE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. You can use the [`BigQueryInsertJobOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/operators/cloud/bigquery.html). 
[Here](https://www.revisitclass.com/gcp/how-to-schedule-and-run-bigquery-using-cloud-composer/) there's a guide on how to use it.